# Component is not rendering any record after converting into .tsx in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I have `ResultTable.jsx` file.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Certificate from './models/certificate';
import axios from 'axios';

const ResultTable = ({certificate}) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(certificate));
    
     return (
        <tr key={certificate.certificateNo}>
        <td>{certificate.certificateNo}</td>
        <td>{certificate.sponser}</td>
        <td>{certificate.protoColNo}</td>
        <td>{certificate.startDate}</td>
        <td>{certificate.endDate}</td>
        <td>{certificate.noOfSubjects}</td>
        <td>{certificate.country}</td>
        <td>{certificate.requestStatus}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    
   
}

export default ResultTable
```

It is properly rendering record in the result table. but when I am converting it into `.tsx` file because my project standards,it is not rendering any record.
I also changed the first line and gave type. `const ResultTable = (certificate:any)`
when I printed in `.tsx` file using `console.log` it is printing the output.

what minor mistake I am doing?
Below is `.tsx` file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Certificate from './models/certificate';

    import axios from 'axios';
    
    const ResultTable = (certificate:any) => {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(certificate));
        
         return (
            <tr key={certificate.certificateNo}>
            <td>{certificate.certificateNo}</td>
            <td>{certificate.sponser}</td>
            <td>{certificate.protoColNo}</td>
            <td>{certificate.startDate}</td>
            <td>{certificate.endDate}</td>
            <td>{certificate.noOfSubjects}</td>
            <td>{certificate.country}</td>
            <td>{certificate.requestStatus}</td>
            </tr>
          )
        
       
    }
    
    export default ResultTable
```

Comment: have you tried to define the `ResultTable` props? like `interface ResultTablePops = {certificateNo:string,sponsor:string ...}` and instead of using `(certificate:any)` use `(certificate:ResultTablePops)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const ResultTable = ({certificate}) => {
```

```
const ResultTable = (certificate:any) => {
```

You swiched from [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the props to not destructuring the props. You need:

```
const ResultTable = ({certificate}:any) => {
```

And of course, this can be improved by defining a type for the props, instead of `any`.